Editors did not reply emails for requesting extension of revised manuscript
I sent an email to the chief editor before the deadline and did not receive any replies. Then I sent emails to other editors (ADMs of my article) in the system but still got no reply before the deadline. The current status of this article shows that it has expired and can be deleted, and the option of "continue" is deactivated. What should I do?
UPDATE: Problem solved! Staff in the publisher's customer service responded to my request and extended the deadline. Thanks for all the replies to this post!

How long has it been since you emailed them? Editors, including the EIC, usually do their editing work on top of full time jobs, so responses are not always fast.

11 days. I also emailed an editorial assistant but still got no reply.

Has the paper been accepted or are you talking about introducing referees' suggestions? I find it unusual that the journal has such a strict deadline on revisions. What sort of journal is it, in what field? Did you already sign any publishing agreement with them?

This paper is in the process of first major revision. A Q1 journal in the field of social sciences. This is my first time encountering such a situation. I used to request extensions for other journals, and those editors are very tolerant. That's very strange...

@Vosoni It's common for journals to give revision deadlines, because they're trying to improve their submission to publication time stats and also because ultimately they make money on published papers, not papers under revision, whether by authors paying fees or subscriptions.

This is irrelevant, as why should the author care about those things the journal wants? Highly selective peer review implies that revisions take longer. Good papers take longer to write. So either you maximize your submission-to-publication time or you maximize your impact factor. These goals contradict each other. And as we see now, the deadline was not really a strict deadline but could be extended.
